# Cannot upgrade to latest version of thunderbird 78

Tags: upgrade, 20.04, thunderbird, daily-build

I need to upgrade to thunderbird 78. I currently have 68 running Ubuntu 20.04. I tried:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-mozilla-daily/ppa
```

and then `update` and `upgrade` but Ubuntu keeps on telling me:

```
thunderbird is already the newest version (1:68.10.0+build1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1).
```

Best

Comment: Thunderbird higher than 68 is not available in any PPA.  If you really need the 78 version you will have to download and manually install it from the [Thunderbird](https://www.thunderbird.net/en-US/) site itself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Ubuntu Desktop Team is [currently working on packaging Thunderbird 78](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/desktop-team-updates-monday-24th-august-2020/17971/). Be patient.

You don't need to add a PPA. The Ubuntu Desktop and Ubuntu Security teams regularly update Firefox and Thunderbird in all supported releases of Ubuntu.

The specific output you received means that nobody uploaded Thunderbird 78 to that PPA.

Comment: Thanks, that is good to know. So that means it will also soon come to 20.04? Or will it be faster in 20.10?

Comment: I am generally the last one to salivate over version numbers of software; I am running 20.04 for safety and stability. But I am forced to use MFA and here: [https://kb.wisc.edu/helpdesk/page.php?id=102005] it says I need TB 77.0b1 or later for that...

Comment: Firefox? The question was about Thunderbird.

Comment: @vanadium good catch. Double-checked and edited.

Comment: TB 78 is now available in Ubuntu 20.10 and the link of this answer also (only) refers to 20.10. Does anyone know if TB 78 will actually be available for 20.04?

Comment: @Mouagip did you review other (newer) weekly Desktop Team updates?

Comment: @user535733 I did now and found a relatively new bug report for a backport, so it will probably come to 20.04 but has no high priority: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/thunderbird/+bug/1895643

Comment: Hasn't TB 78 been released in early Decembre? Why is it still not in the ppa for focal fossa? I could not find information nowhere. Are the developers still packaging TB78 for Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: @JES 1) A PPA is **NOT** the Ubuntu Repositories. 2) Please do not hijack answers with follow-up questions. This is not a threaded discussion forum. 3) This answer shows you how to find the information yourself on the developers' discussion site. 4) A trivial query of http://packages.ubuntu.com will also answer your question.

Answer (score 7):

You can use this ppa which provides the packaged version with no deps like libc6.
Thunderbird is actually locked to version 68 on focal, and on 20.10 it is on version 78, but it forces using libc6 2.32.

Any way just use it from here https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/ubuntu_mozilla_security?dist=focal

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-mozilla-security/ppa 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install thunderbird
```

You may also install `thunderbird-fr` to use French translation for example.

Comment: This may be the marked solution! Thanks!

Comment: Please consider the following statement from the mentioned ppa:
"_Staging PPA for Mozilla and other browser-related security updates. Unless you are 
testing updates, you should NOT install packages from this PPA._"
Hence, this should be a workaround for the question but not the way to go to keep thunderbird up-to-date on your apt based system.

Answer (score 2):

If you real need new version, you can use Snap Store

https://snapcraft.io/thunderbird

Comment: will install also v68, so it doesn't help

Comment: It gets 78.7 now - `sudo snap install thunderbird` or go to the url in the answer

Comment: or maybe just `snap install thunderbird`