# How can I make a package available in Synapit (or apt or...)

Tags: apt, package-management, thunderbird

Thuderbird 78 is annonced for times...

[Cannot upgrade to latest version of thunderbird 78](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1270573/cannot-upgrade-to-latest-version-of-thunderbird-78) (August 2020)

The package seems available on launchpad since 24 augut 2020 :

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/thunderbird/1:78.2.0+build1-0ubuntu1

but still not available on Ubuntu 20.04. i can only have a 1:68.10.0+build1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 where there is a big problem with Lightnings.

Is it a way to make this package available on 20.04 with an other way than ppa:ubuntu-mozilla-security/ppa ?

Answer (score 0):

The Ubuntu Desktop Team are [working](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/thunderbird-lts-update/20819) on bringing Thunderbird 78 to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. At the time of writing, it's currently in the [pending SRU queue](https://people.canonical.com/%7Eubuntu-archive/pending-sru.html).
You can track progress on [bug 1895643](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/thunderbird/+bug/1895643).